# USB Type-C display adapter is not recognized at all

Tags: hdmi, usb-c

First of all, sorry if my question is off-topic. I'm new here and I don't know where to ask, so direct me appropriatelly please.

So I'm running an [ASUS X570ZD](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Home/Everyday-use/ASUS-X570/helpdesk_knowledge?model2Name=ASUS-Laptop-X570ZD) laptop
and I've got Kubuntu 20.04 installed.

So, I wanted to add 2 external monitors to that laptop. I got a USB-C port (without too much documentation on that), So I went ahead a bought this thingy here [Blueendless 5-In-1 triple discplay USB-C hub](https://www.banggood.com/Blueendless-5-In-1-Triple-Display-USB-C-Hub-Docking-Station-Adapter-With-USB-3_0-or-Dual-HDMI-4K-HD-Display-or-1080P-VGA-or-100W-Type-C-PD-Charging-p-1697849.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN). It says it works with windows, mac and linux, but documentation is also lacking.

So when I plug it in, nothing happens. It has an internal LED which lights up, but other than that, there's nothing. It won't recognize devices plugged into the USB type-A port of the adapter either.

I tried running `lsusb -t` with and without the adapter and nothing changes

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

I tried logging the output of `dmesg -w` but nothing happens when I plug the adapter in or out.

I tried pluging the USB-C port on the adapter to an external power supply too, and nothing happend.

I updated laptop to the latest Firmware, but still nothing.

The 2 HDMI monitors and the laptop are otherwise working OK. However, I don't have another laptop (e.g. a macbook with thunderbolt 3) to test the adapter.

Is there anything else I can check/try before deciding that it's a hardware issue? (incompatibility or fault adapter or fault USB-C port).

EDIT: I tried to connect the hub to another laptop which had a USB-C with a "D" marking and was running Windows 10, and it worked just fine! Now I'm thinking to upgrade my hardware and get, say, an Intel Nook which presumably supports video-over-USB-c with a Thunderbolt connector. Are there reasons to believe that my hub won't work with the Nook and/or Ubuntu/Kubuntu (i.e. does Windows have proprietary usb-video drivers which cannot be found in Ubuntu)?

Comment: I think the USB hub portion on these kinds of adapters should always work, even if the HDMI features are not supported, so possibly you got a dud.. unfortunately USB-C is sometimes still has non-standard whackyness and not everything works together (especially things like dual monitors on one connector, esp. on a non-mac computer). try turning the usb-c connector around (it's supposed to be symmetrical, but occasionally there are broken implementations...), and you could also try it in Windows (which you can run from a USB drive, though I think you need a windows machine to make the usb)

Comment: @JonasCz Hey mate, thanks for the input. I tried the hub with another laptop which had a USB-C port with a "D" marking (last one [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/84794)), presumably DisplayPort. The laptop had Windows 10 and the hub worked fine as soon as it was connected (not installed anything). I want to get a Nook mini-PC which supports video over USB-C with a Thunderbolt connector. Is there a reason to think my hub won't work with this? It there a reason to believe it won't work with Ubuntu/Kubuntu?